# Ruby on Rails: deploying project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

When I try to deploy my project to heroku, it writes me "we are sorry but something went wrong". I'm newbie and I don't know where is problem.

There is one thing I completely don't understand: where can i find settings for production mode? I toke it from postgres.heroku.com.

My gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'pg'
gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
gem 'gravatar_image_tag', '1.0.0.pre2'
gem "will_paginate", :git => "https://github.com/p7r/will_paginate.git", :branch => "rails3"
gem 'yaml_db', :git => 'git://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db.git'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'faker', '0.3.1'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
end
```

My database:yml

```
development:
  host: localhost
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: app_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: nikita
  password: '0761'

test:
  host: localhost
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: app_test
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: nikita
  password: '0761'

production:
  host: ec2-54-243-125-2.compute-1.amazonaws.com
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: d8ndsoaide8227
  pool: 5
  port:  5432
  username: gglrqupemilczi
  password: 'TK02bb-oXqLHD9fTGi_FnahKMl'
```

My logs from heroku:

```
2013-03-26T20:38:10+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.12 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:30982
2013-03-26T20:38:10+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-03-26T20:38:10+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-03-26T20:38:10+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2013-03-26T20:38:10+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-26 20:38:10] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2013-03-26T20:38:10+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-26 20:38:10] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=30982
2013-03-26T20:38:10+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-26 20:38:10] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-03-26T20:38:11+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 46.72.99.61 at 2013-03-26 20:38:22 +0000
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (18.6ms)
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (0.3ms)
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=ancient-cliffs-5913.herokuapp.com fwd="46.72.99.61" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=841ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_menu.html.erb (149.2ms)
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 295ms
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:42:in `user_from_remember_token'
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/user.rb:32:in `authenticate_with_salt'
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/_menu.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts__menu_html_erb__3915312893639424325_36046660'
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:13:in `current_user'
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:                    <li class="active"><%= link_to "Главная", home_path %></li>
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:                <ul class="nav">
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:                    <% if signed_in? %>
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:                <!--<li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>-->
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:                   <li><%= link_to "Меню", menu_path %></li>
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__796508102528627285_36433920'
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:                   <li><%= link_to "Заказ", "#" %></li>
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:17:in `signed_in?'
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-26T20:38:23+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=ancient-cliffs-5913.herokuapp.com fwd="46.72.99.61" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=15ms status=200 bytes=0
2013-03-26T20:42:50+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2013-03-26T20:43:19+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v16 created by nikskalkin@gmail.com
2013-03-26T20:43:20+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy aa717ce by nikskalkin@gmail.com
2013-03-26T20:43:20+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2013-03-26T20:43:20+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2013-03-26T20:43:22+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 46174`
2013-03-26T20:43:22+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-03-26T20:43:22+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-26 20:43:22] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2013-03-26T20:43:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
2013-03-26T20:43:25+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-03-26T20:43:25+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-03-26T20:43:27+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-03-26T20:43:27+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-03-26T20:43:27+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-03-26T20:43:27+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2013-03-26T20:43:27+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.12 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:46174
2013-03-26T20:43:28+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-26 20:43:28] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-03-26T20:43:28+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-26 20:43:28] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2013-03-26T20:43:28+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-26 20:43:28] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=46174
2013-03-26T20:43:33+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2013-03-26T20:43:33+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2013-03-26T20:43:34+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-03-26T20:43:34+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 46.72.99.61 at 2013-03-26 20:43:50 +0000
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (8.0ms)
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (0.3ms)
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 123ms
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_menu.html.erb (19.6ms)
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:                <ul class="nav">
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:                    <li class="active"><%= link_to "Главная", home_path %></li>
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:                    <% if signed_in? %>
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:                   <li><%= link_to "Меню", menu_path %></li>
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/user.rb:32:in `authenticate_with_salt'
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:                   <li><%= link_to "Заказ", "#" %></li>
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:17:in `signed_in?'
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:13:in `current_user'
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1372676093577475516_38604840'
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/_menu.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts__menu_html_erb___1404536040465121211_38027760'
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:42:in `user_from_remember_token'
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:                <!--<li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>-->
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=ancient-cliffs-5913.herokuapp.com fwd="46.72.99.61" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=292ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=ancient-cliffs-5913.herokuapp.com fwd="46.72.99.61" dyno=web.1 connect=7ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=0
root@Nikita-PC:/home/nikita/rails/invent# heroku logs
2013-03-26T20:38:10+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.12 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:30982
2013-03-26T20:38:10+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-03-26T20:38:10+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-03-26T20:38:10+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2013-03-26T20:38:10+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-26 20:38:10] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2013-03-26T20:38:10+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-26 20:38:10] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=30982
2013-03-26T20:38:10+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-26 20:38:10] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-03-26T20:38:11+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 46.72.99.61 at 2013-03-26 20:38:22 +0000
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (18.6ms)
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (0.3ms)
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=ancient-cliffs-5913.herokuapp.com fwd="46.72.99.61" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=841ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_menu.html.erb (149.2ms)
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 295ms
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:42:in `user_from_remember_token'
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/user.rb:32:in `authenticate_with_salt'
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/_menu.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts__menu_html_erb__3915312893639424325_36046660'
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:13:in `current_user'
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:                    <li class="active"><%= link_to "Главная", home_path %></li>
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:                <ul class="nav">
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:                    <% if signed_in? %>
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:                <!--<li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>-->
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:                   <li><%= link_to "Меню", menu_path %></li>
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__796508102528627285_36433920'
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:                   <li><%= link_to "Заказ", "#" %></li>
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:17:in `signed_in?'
2013-03-26T20:38:22+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-26T20:38:23+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=ancient-cliffs-5913.herokuapp.com fwd="46.72.99.61" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=15ms status=200 bytes=0
2013-03-26T20:42:50+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2013-03-26T20:43:19+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v16 created by nikskalkin@gmail.com
2013-03-26T20:43:20+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy aa717ce by nikskalkin@gmail.com
2013-03-26T20:43:20+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2013-03-26T20:43:20+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2013-03-26T20:43:22+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 46174`
2013-03-26T20:43:22+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-03-26T20:43:22+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-26 20:43:22] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2013-03-26T20:43:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
2013-03-26T20:43:25+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-03-26T20:43:25+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-03-26T20:43:27+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-03-26T20:43:27+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-03-26T20:43:27+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-03-26T20:43:27+00:00 app[web.
1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2013-03-26T20:43:27+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.12 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:46174
2013-03-26T20:43:28+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-26 20:43:28] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-03-26T20:43:28+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-26 20:43:28] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2013-03-26T20:43:28+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-26 20:43:28] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=46174
2013-03-26T20:43:33+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2013-03-26T20:43:33+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2013-03-26T20:43:34+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-03-26T20:43:34+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 46.72.99.61 at 2013-03-26 20:43:50 +0000
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (8.0ms)
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (0.3ms)
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 123ms
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_menu.html.erb (19.6ms)
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:                <ul class="nav">
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:                    <li class="active"><%= link_to "Главная", home_path %></li>
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:                    <% if signed_in? %>
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:                   <li><%= link_to "Меню", menu_path %></li>
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/user.rb:32:in `authenticate_with_salt'
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:                   <li><%= link_to "Заказ", "#" %></li>
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:17:in `signed_in?'
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:13:in `current_user'
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1372676093577475516_38604840'
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/_menu.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts__menu_html_erb___1404536040465121211_38027760'
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:42:in `user_from_remember_token'
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:                <!--<li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>-->
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=ancient-cliffs-5913.herokuapp.com fwd="46.72.99.61" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=292ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-03-26T20:43:50+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=ancient-cliffs-5913.herokuapp.com fwd="46.72.99.61" dyno=web.1 connect=7ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=0
```

Comment: You should change your production database password; you've just compromised it by pasting it above.

Comment: As a quick note, make sure you change your username and passwords listed in your database.yml file.

Comment: also, being Heroku they rewrite your database.yml when you deploy anyhow so you don't need it.

Comment: not only that, but you should *never* put credentials inside source code. always use environment variables

Comment: Also, if you have an app with heroku, you should attach databases with `heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql` instead of from postgres.heroku.com. The latter is for people who want databases without their app being on heroku

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to do `heroku run rake db:migrate` after pushing your code.

FYI - to change your postgres password do `heroku pg:credentials DATABASE --reset` since you've just posted it above.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run `heroku logs` at the console, and that will show your the error log from heroku.